# How to detect when "0" is supplied as a form/$_POST value?

Tags: php, forms, post, isset

I'm trying to determine whether or not there is a value passed, but the value CAN be `0` ...

`isset` always returns true, and `empty` returns false because the value is `0`

How can I get around this?

Comment: I'm confused by what you're looking for. Zero is a value. Are you looking for any non-empty value? That's what `!empty` does. What is your range of valid input?

Comment: So you either get true (`isset`) or false (`empty`). Pick one, there's no "half truth" when dealing with booleans.

Comment: Maybe if($var >= 0){}

Comment: @Ben, Alex responded below with exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: "whether or not there is a value" means `!empty`

Comment: `and empty returns false because the value is 0` That isn't expected. Empty should return true on a 0

Comment: @oliakaoil empty(0) == empty("0") == FALSE, to `empty`, 0 is not a value

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky It's not expected logically, [***it's just PHP***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: This has to be, hands down, the most ridiculous SO question and answer set I've ever seen.

Comment: @oliakaoil How is it ridiculous? The very fact that empty has been *repeatedly misunderstood* makes it worthwhile, IMOHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
bool array_key_exists ( mixed $key , array $array )
```

like

```
if (array_key_exists("var1", $_POST)) {
    // positive case, var1 was posted
    if ($_POST["var1"] == 0){
        // var1 was posted and 0
    }else{
        // var1 was posted and is not 0
    }
}
```

more details are given at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

Comment: This isn't exactly what I did, but it gave me the hint to use `Input::has('name')` since I've using Laravel. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The values of the `$_POST` array is all strings. Use the `===` operator:

```
if ($_POST['key'] === '0') {
   // do things
}
```

Comment: It could be a non-"0" value.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply checking whether the value is empty:

```
if (isset($_POST['key']) && $_POST['key'] !== '')) {
  //'key' is set and not empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> if (isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != 0)) {
>     /*your Code*/
>   }

Answer (score -1):

All post values are strings, so consider:

```
isset($a[i]) && strlen($a[i])
```

Which will be true if and only if *a* value (*except* "an empty string") is supplied. Unlike with `empty`,  [which would return FALSE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), this will also detect when "0" was passed as a value. Unlike the proposed solution, it will not be true when "" was supplied: thus it truly detects when *a* value was passed.

---

Also, `array_key_exists` and `isset` for $_POST keys will work the same, as there will no NULL values; arguably the critical check is that for a non-empty string. Once a value *has* been determined to exist (per the above/desired rules), it can be processed as appropriate - e.g. `if ($a[i] > 0)` or `if ($a[i] == 0)`.